# Возможно ли добавить в стандартную панель FolderBrowserDialog строки для ручного ввода директории?

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли добавить в стандартную панель FolderBrowserDialog строки для ручного ввода директории?

Пользователю нужно предложить имя папки, а он уже либо соглашается с именем либо правит имя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К сожалению, нельзя модифицировать FolderBrowserDialog, так как он помечен как sealed. 
Пример модификации можно посмотреть в [статье](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14454/Extended-Folder-Browser)

Answer (score 0):

Как алтернатива использовать SaveFileDialog. Символ \u200B скроет файлы:

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.CheckFileExists = false;
sfd.Title = "Выберите директорию";
sfd.FileName = "Выберите директорию";
sfd.Filter = "Выберите директорию (имя файла будет проигнорировано)|*.*\u200B";
sfd.ShowDialog();
```